# Monotonicity of evaluation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-theory

> Let `<` denote the semantic approximation order in Haskell.
>
> Then the *monotonicity of evaluation* guarantees that if `e1 < e2` then
>   `[[e1]] < [[e2]]`, where `e1`, `e2` are expressions and `[[e1]]`
>   denotes the evaluation of `e1`.

In the notes I am following this is noted as a very useful property to reason about Haskell programs, but there are no examples given.

Can somebody give me one example of such reasoning?

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem some notes in Spanish from my college teacher of declarative programming

Comment: I suspect your teacher means _monotonicity_, which is rather less of an editorialisation than _monotony_ 

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson ups, now fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `undefined <= 4`, by monotonicity we can conclude `undefined + 12 <= 4 + 12`. Indeed, the former is `undefined`, while the latter is `16`. We also have `[undefined] <= [4]`, or more in general `f undefined <= f 4`.

The intuition is this: assume `f :: Int -> T`. When `f x` is called, either `f` demands the integer argument `x` or it does not. If it does, `f undefined` will be undefined (crash / exception / non termination), so `f 4` will surely be `>=` than. If it does not demand `x`, then `f undefined = f 4 = f x` for any `x`, so `<=` holds again, trivially.

Things become more complex with more complex types. If `g :: (Int,Int) -> T` we have

```
g undefined
<= g (undefined, undefined)
<= g (undefined, 2)
<= g (3, 2)
```

The very rough idea behind monotonicity is: if we pass a function a more defined argument, we get a more defined (or equally defined) result. Or more bluntly: less crashing input, less crashing output.

Comment: This has been useful for me to read, but I want to stress that I am looking for practical examples in day to day programming.

Comment: It's not a technique you actively use; it's just a concept to help describe the underlying semantics of your code. Practically speaking, you want to avoid `undefined` as much as possible.

Comment: @Jsevillamol It has not frequent applications. Perhaps a small one is: after you test `length [undefined, undefined] == 2` there is no need to also test `length [1,2] == 2` and `length [4,-4] == 2` etc. since they must be `==2` by monotonicity. If the first test passes, the other must have the same result. It's more a technique for _reasoning_ about code (e.g. proving properties on the code) rather than for practical _programming_.